# How to store the spark output to rdbms database?

Tags: apache-spark

I have started using spark recently, I have a use case where I need to process the file and store the output ot postgre database. I am able to read the file and process it, I am not able to store the processed data to db. Can some one please suggest how can i save the output to db?

Thanks,,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the database is accessible from all workers node, you can use `foreachPartition` to save the output. Pseudocode:

```
rdd.foreachPartition { records =>
  // Connect to the database 
  records.foreach { r => 
    // Loop over records and save
  }
  // Close the connection to the db
}
```